# How do i turn off the remote debugging in MS EDGE in Selenium JAVA?

Tags: selenium-edgedriver

the below code is able to launch EDGE but is saying to turn off remote debugger during execution.
I added the argument to disable the remote debugger (disable-features=msEdgeDevToolsWdpRemoteDebugging), but somehow when i open edge://version [image: edge version SS], there is an entry for "remote-debugging-port=0", which i think re-enables the remote debugging.

```
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", TestConfig.getProperty("browserDriverPath") + "msedgedriver.exe");
            EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
            List<String> args = Arrays.asList("disable-features=msEdgeDevToolsWdpRemoteDebugging", "ie-mode-force");
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("args", args);
            options.setCapability("ms:edgeOptions", map);
            //options.setCapability("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("remote-debugging-port=0"));
            options.setCapability("excludeSwitches", "remote-debugging-port=0");
            EdgeDriver msdriver = new EdgeDriver(options);
            driver = msdriver;
```

below is the line of capabilities captured by the logger during execution:

*Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: msedge, browserVersion: 101.0.1210.53, javascriptEnabled: true, ms:edgeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:14952}, msedge: {msedgedriverVersion: 101.0.1210.53 (019dbf6dd738..., userDataDir: C:\Users}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}*

i would just like to find out how to completely disable the remote debugger using any edgeoption arguments. Thanks.

OS: windows Server 2012
Selenium : 3.141.0
EdgeDriver: current.